# Ctools Multi step form throws error when form_validate is from another file

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, forms

Ctools Multi step form throws error when form_validate is from another file even I had included the file using module_load_include.

As per [this example](http://internetdevels.com/blog/ctools-multistep-wizard-example) I used a function not from the current file but by using module_load_include this is working fine. But when it comes to form_validate it is throwing an error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, we need to include using the below function

```
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'module_name', 'module_name.file');
```